# Как настроить bridge over bonding в RHEL 6.4 Server?

Tags: linux, eth0, rhel, сервер, сеть

Имеется установленная система ([rhel-server-6.4-x86_64-dvd.iso](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4358795)). Поверх которой установлен KVM ([инструкция по установке](http://habrahabr.ru/post/168791/)). Хост-машине и guest-машине назначены собственные IP-адреса, для этого по инструкции с хабра настроен мост **br0**. Все работает. Теперь надо сделать bridge over bonding.

Ставлю на хосте следующие настройки:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 DEVICE=eth0HWADDR=f0:92:1c:0f:76:f8MASTER=bond0SLAVE=yesONBOOT=yes[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1DEVICE=eth1HWADDR=F0:92:1C:0F:76:FCMASTER=bond0SLAVE=yesONBOOT=yes[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 DEVICE=bond0ONBOOT=yesBRIDGE="br0"[root@server ~]# cat /etc/modprobe.conf alias bond0 bondingoptions bond0 mode=1 miimon=100[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0 DEVICE="br0"NM_CONTROLLED="no"ONBOOT="yes"TYPE="Bridge"BOOTPROTO="static"IPADDR="10.2.26.39"GATEWAY="10.2.26.1"MTU="1500"NETMASK="255.255.255.0"DEFROUTE="yes"IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="yes"IPV6INIT="no"NAME="System br0"
```

Проверяю:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)Primary Slave: NoneCurrently Active Slave: eth1MII Status: upMII Polling Interval (ms): 100Up Delay (ms): 0Down Delay (ms): 0Slave Interface: eth0MII Status: downSpeed: UnknownDuplex: UnknownLink Failure Count: 0Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:76:f8Slave queue ID: 0Slave Interface: eth1MII Status: upSpeed: 10000 MbpsDuplex: fullLink Failure Count: 0Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:76:fcSlave queue ID: 0
```

**eth0** в дауне. Хотя я ожидал увидеть нечто типа следующего:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)Primary Slave: NoneCurrently Active Slave: eth0MII Status: upMII Polling Interval (ms): 100Up Delay (ms): 0Down Delay (ms): 0Slave Interface: eth0MII Status: upSpeed: 10000 MbpsDuplex: fullLink Failure Count: 0Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:d5:e8Slave queue ID: 0Slave Interface: eth1MII Status: upSpeed: 10000 MbpsDuplex: fullLink Failure Count: 0Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:d5:ecSlave queue ID: 0
```

Вопрос собственно в сабже, как настроить bridge over bonding в RHEL 6.4 Server?

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно. Вы хотите active-backup, т.е когда один интерфейс работает а второй опущен и в backup.

> [root@server ~]# cat /etc/modprobe.conf
>
> alias bond0 bonding
>
> options bond0 mode=1 miimon=100

Но пишете что хотите видеть когда у вас два интерфейса в active  режиме, это товарищ, уже другой режим.

Comment: Т.е. один интерфейс всегда опущен в режиме active-backup? Тогда мне не понятно почему у меня на другом сервере без бриджа, с только одним бондингом оба интерфейса подняты.

Comment: какой там mode?

Comment: тоже fault-tolerance (active-backup), последний лог в моем посте. это с другого сервера (на котором только бондинг без бриджа). я ожидал на сервере на котором бондинг+бридж тоже подобная картина будет.

Comment: Я понял. У вас он просто опущен. Поднимите же его ifup eth0.

Comment: Даю команду ifup eth0 и ничего не происходит. Никаких сообщений. cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 по-прежнему показывает, что интерфейс eth0 опущен. Вообще у него ONBOOT=yes так что он должен автоматически подниматься при загрузке ОС.

Comment: а что в dmesg?

Comment: dmesg: http://pastebin.com/bZzCjFJn я в его выводе честно говоря не разбираюсь. cat /var/log/dmesg |grep -i eth0 показывает be2net 0000:04:00.0: eth0: Emulex OneConnect 10Gbps NIC(be3) port 0

Comment: вот ifconfig еще http://pastebin.com/fjHPvDxR